# Error getting the .last()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [this structure](https://jsfiddle.net/ror1mm0r/)

I want to get the last message, im trying to use the .last() function:

```
$('#user-chat-' + data.de).find('#load-msgs').last().html()
```

But the jquery returns all the results inside the div, not the last result. Someone knows why im getting this error? (The selector is correct, im getting the result, but i don't get the last)
Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to show all the code

Comment: **Get last `div`** `$('#user-chat-' + data.de).find('#load-msgs div').last().html()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

           $("#load-msgs").last().find('div span').html()

//OR
           $("#load-msgs div span").last().html()    
    })
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ror1mm0r/2/)

The html from your script :

```
<div class="row" id="load-msgs">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <span class="message-box message-other" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="18:28">
         lewpwa </span>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <span class="message-box message-other" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="18:28">
         oppa   </span>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <span class="message-box message-other" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="18:36">
         oppa   </span>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <span class="message-box message-other" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="18:36">
         oppa   </span>
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`find('#load-msgs').last()` - return last element of the collection of elements with ID `load-msgs` which is <strike>invalid</strike>/absurd/unnecessary. You need children.

Use,

```
find('#load-msgs div').last()
```

or

```
find('#load-msgs').children().last()
```

Comment: _which is invalid_, It _is_ valid

Comment: It's valid ... it's just redundant or unnecessary but it's valid

Comment: @Tushar, by invalid I meant, unnecessary as multiple elements with same ID is invalid markup., Tweaked my answer.

Comment: @ShaunakD  U dont need to use `find` Unique id `load-msgs` already  there in the parent hierarchy  `$("#load-msgs").last().html()` should work

Comment: @Tushar: In what way is using the same `id` on more than one element remotely valid? From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): *"The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree..."*

Answer (score 0):

`find('#load-msgs')` will only target element with id load-msgs. You will need to target immediate child divs inside `#load-msgs` element and then use last selector or method on returned set of divs.

also as IDs are unique you don't need `#user-chat` selector and then find element in it. You can directly get element using id selector `#load-msgs`:

```
$('#load-msgs > div').last().html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#user-chat-' + data.de).find('#load-msgs').children('div').last().html();
```